# spring-boot v2 actuator selector

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Based on [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0#comment-4050095879), I have tried to implement an actuator endpoint like this:

```
@Component 
@Endpoint(id = "test/filter/configurator")
@RequiredArgsConstructor 
public class AdvisorFilterConfigurator {

private final AdvisorFilterConfig filterConfig;

@ReadOperation 
public Boolean rewrite(@Selector Boolean enable) { 
  filterConfig.setEnable(enable); 
  return filterConfig.isEnable(); 
 } 
}
```

When I am try to access `http://localhost:9992/admin/test/filter/configurator/true`, it says `Missing parameters: enable`, as it can be seen on this screenshot:

[image]

I can only access that endpoint this way:
`http://localhost:9992/admin/test/filter/configurator/{anystring}?enable=true`.

Am I doing something wrong or this is issue with actuator?

Answer (score 4):

The "missing parameters" bits happen because you've not compiled the code with `-parameters` as [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-custom-input).

If you didn't you should see something like this in the logs

> 2018-08-21 10:35:21.098  INFO 78181 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/test/{arg0}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map)

Once you've made sure the code is compiled with `-parameters` you should see something like this instead:

> 2018-08-21 10:34:20.802  INFO 77977 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/test/{enable}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map)

Notice that in the first case the selector is `{arg0}` (auto-generated parameter name when the information is not available) while in the second it is `{enable}`.

You can also run the app from the command line if you're using Maven and the spring boot parent (`mvn clean spring-boot:run`) as it takes care of enabling `-parameters` automatically.

I've also created [#14159](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14159) to check how we can improve that error message.